# Flutter API response not being stored, showing previous value

Tags: flutter, dart

I am writing a signup form in flutter, and once the user presses the "signup" button, I send the info to the backend, and get a response. If the response is that writing the user fails (duplicate email, invalid data), I want to put the response text to the screen with an AlertDialog.

My problem is, when I store the response in variables and then check the value of them, they don’t seem to update until after they are needed.

My function to get the api response looks like this:

```
int apiResponseCode;
String apiResponseText;

void createUser(xxxxx) async {
    final http.Response response = await http.post('xxxxxx', headers: <String, String>{'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',},
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        "data": "xxxxxx",
      }),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> resp = jsonDecode(response.body);
      setState(() { this.apiResponseCode = resp['response_code']; this.apiResponseText = resp['response_text']; });
      }
  }
```

And then my form submit button widget looks like this:

```
RoundedButton(
                          text: "SIGNUP",
                          press: () {
                            createUser(xxxxxxxx);
                            if (this.apiResponseCode != 1) {
                              showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                child: AlertDialog(
                                  title: Text(
                                    "Oops! Please Fix the error below! ",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor),
                                  ),
                                  content: Text(
                                    this.apiResponseText,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor),
                                  ),
                                  actions: [
                                    FlatButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                        },
                                        child: Text(
                                          "OK",
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: kPrimaryLightTextColor),
                                        )),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            } else {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) {
                                    return TwoStepValidationScreen();
                                  },
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                          }),
```

The first time the submit button gets pushed, the `this.apiResponseText` and `this.apiResponseCode` are null/empty, and then the second time the button gets pushed, the variables hold the values that they should have had previously. For example, if the first time the button gets pushed the api response is valid, the screen will output a failure. But then the second time the button gets pushed the apiResponse is invalid (because that user has already been created), but the button works for they user and they get navigated to the next page.

If anyone knows why the responses arent being storing until after the function is called, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have to change this code `press: () { createUser(xxxxxxxx);` to `press: () async { await createUser(xxxxxxxx);`

Comment: Happy to know that it helped you. Happy Coding !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue happens because your `createUser` function is an asynchronous function and you are not waiting for it to finish. When you check `this.apiResponseCode` immediately, the execution of that function is still in progress and that's why you are not getting proper result.

To fix that issue, change your code to:

```
press: () async {
   await createUser(xxxxxxxx);
   if (this.apiResponseCode != 1) {
     // other code
   }
}
```